# Copy Events from ICS Stream into a different calendar (O365)

Tags: python, calendar, applescript, icalendar

I have all my trips organised at trips and they offer a nice ics stream.
My Problem is that my company calendar is shared with others (within O365) and they obviously don't see all the stuff from the TripIt ics stream and this is causing sometimes confusion.

Can anyone think of any way (Mac automator, Apple Script, Python, etc) to read the Tripit ics stream and copy the events into the O365 calendar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To 'copy' the events, normally one would 'import' the ics url, instead of (or as well as) subscribing, but it's a snapshot - no updates.